# virtual keyboard does not appear in QML-based application on Nokia 5230

Tags: qt, keyboard, qml

I have a QML-based application which is deployed on my Nokia 5230 phone, there are several TextInput components, when the component takes the input focus, input method status indicator changed, but virtual keyboard does not appear.

My application is full-screen displayed by calling QDeclarativeView::showFullScreen(), I have tried 4 different input methods including the official AknFEP, all have the same problem.

Did I miss something?

BTW, it works fine on desktop or in Qt simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Qt are you using?

Did you try opening the VKB manually?

```
TextInput {
    id: textInput

    activeFocusOnPress: false

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            textInput.forceActiveFocus();
            textInput.openSoftwareInputPanel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to open the Windows Touch-KeyBoard for a Windows 8 Touch-Application? I can't find a way.

Comment: Are you kidding!? Why you have to do such hackery for TextInput to work with VKB? Looks like QT not really touch devices friendly.... :(

Comment: That is an answer for Symbian^1 from 2011! We now have Qt 5.1 instead of Qt 4.6 and QML has progressed a lot.