# show keyboard on focus qml

Tags: qt, keyboard, qml

I'm trying to show the keyboard when the view loads and the TextInput has focus.

```
TextInput {
  id: textInput
  focus: true
}
```

I thought the keyboard would show up automatically since the text input has focus. But it doesn't.

So I tried sending this event to the view, but it doesn't show the keyboard on the first load. Please note that I'm loading this qml dynamically using a QML Loader on the first load. The subsequent loads of this view, shows the keyboard as expected.

```
QEvent event(QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel);
bool sent = QApplication::sendEvent(iView, &event);
```

Answer (score 1):

See this discussion.
[virtual keyboard does not appear in QML-based application on Nokia 5230](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208296/virtual-keyboard-does-not-appear-in-qml-based-application-on-nokia-5230)

Try to bring the software input panel with the use of Component.onLoaded:{ }.